# Dual Display Settings lost after blank screen / lock

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 recently and have just started having this problem.

I have a dual-monitor setup with two different monitor manufacturers. Ubuntu detects the monitor I use as my 'primary' as #2 (if this matters). In Display Settings, I have set this as my 'Primary Display' and moved it to the left of display #1.

After the computer switches to a lock / blank screen, my primary monitor goes to 'sleep'. When I return to the computer, this monitor is not 'woken' - the secondary monitor turns on and allows me to login, but I have to go and change the display settings again to turn on the primary monitor and set the correct layout.

This started happening after the upgrade and worked fine before. Has anyone else seen this - is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to solve it I have edited the file

```
~/.config/monitors.xml
```

There I had 4 *logicalmonitor* configurations, instead of only 2.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer and add a bit more info? Just stating that you edited a file is not enough for your answer to be helpful for the OP and other users. It would be much better if you could at least add the content of your `~/.config/monitors.xml` file, or even better if you could modify the content of the file to suit the OP's case. Thanks!